# resize both width and height of a div while window resize using css

Tags: css, resize, height, width

is there any way to resize both width and height of a div in correlation with the browser resize using css? I have already achieved width resize but can't find how to resize the height in correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use viewport-percentage lengths:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

If you wanted to create a square that maintains an aspect ratio, you could use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9y3axnsn/)

```
.maintain-aspect-ratio {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25vw;
}
```

These lengths are supported in most modern browsers - [support can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

---

If you want an alternative with more browser support, you could always use the [`padding-top` trick](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) to maintain the aspect ratio.

[**Alternative Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e06ezvpr/)

```
.maintain-aspect-ratio {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
}
.maintain-aspect-ratio:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 ratio */
}
```