# How to resize both rows and columns of a div using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Considering this below example we have a table with the size of **592 * 455** . The image is shown below , which is perfect.

[image: Image 1]

Now if i try to resize the width of the table as **357 * 455** the image will shrink and it will display as

[image: Image 2]

Now the issue with the resizing the height of the div, If i do it as **592 * 222** , The image displayed below

[image: Image 3]

Now the bottom half of the image is not getting displayed, Can i get the image shrunk as it was when i resized the width. So i can get the full div which is shrunk?

I got a reference [resize both width and height of a div while window resize using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881469/resize-both-width-and-height-of-a-div-while-window-resize-using-css), but still not able to solve the issue.

How to overcome this problem?

Code is mentioned below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show your code - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: i do not understand what you mean here  - *Now the bottom half of the image is not getting displayed, Can i get the image shrunk as it was when i resized the width. So i can get the full div which is shrunk?* -   Your code has no image nor enough content to see if anything really disappear. Do you want both boxes always the same height, do you want them to stack on top each other on small screen, what do you mean with resizing ? to keep a ratio, show a scrollbar, reduce width & increase height according to content, ...?

Comment: while waiting for a feed back... with flex, the minimal CSS with a break point at average 700px  could be `.row {display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}.column {flex:1;min-width:350px}` .

Comment: @G-Cyr Whenever i resize my browser window both the rows and columns of the div should be responsive

Comment: what do you mean by responsive ? is the answer below or the minimal code i proposed are close to what you need ? (@jason IsMyName answer's) *should be responsive* does not answer my earlier questions btw

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. This will make the image resized but still remain the ratio

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:230px;
  max-height:95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you

```
<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Simply add display:flex to the parent</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalH eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalH eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalH eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>            

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex to the parent and flex:1 to the boxes</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>            

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS WITH MARGINS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex, justify-content: space-between; to the parent and give a width to the boxes that totals to less than 100%. E.g. These boxes have a width of 32% each. The remaining width of 4% (i.e. 32 x 3 = 96%) will be used to create the space between the boxes and simulate margins. No need to remove margins on the first and last child!</p>
  <div class="equalHMWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHM eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHM eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHM eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS WITH MARGINS IN MULTIPLE ROWS</h1>
  <p>Building on the above example, just give bottom margins to the boxes. Add a flex-wrap: wrap to the parent, so that boxes go to the next line when they run out of space in a 'row'.</p>
  <div class="equalHMRWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo <br> boo </div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS WITH MARGINS IN MULTIPLE ROWS and VARIABLE NO OF BOXES</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex, flex-wrap: wrap to the parent and give a width to the boxes. Give margins to the boxes and remove the left and right margins of the first and last box in each 'row' using the nth-of-type selector. Unlike the previous example, justify-content: space-between on the parent does not work for an uneven number of boxes, because if there are five boxes in all, the third and fifth will align to the left and right of the perceived 'row'.</p>
  <div class="equalHMVWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHMV eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">clue</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">boo <br> boo </div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.paddingBlock {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.eqWrap {
  display: flex;
}

.eq {
  padding: 10px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.equalHW {
  flex: 1;
}

.equalHMWrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.equalHM {
  width: 32%;
}

.equalHMRWrap {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equalHMR {
  width: 32%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.equalHMVWrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equalHMV {
  width: 32%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.equalHMV:nth-of-type(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.equalHMV:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done using display:flex, it can be done other ways such as display:grid. But I find display flex is easiest.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-title {
 text-align: center;
}

.row {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1248px;
 margin: 0 auto;

 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap; /* allows the boxes to take up multiple rows in more content is added */
 flex-direction: row; /* direction you want the boxes to sit */
 align-items: stretch; /* how you want the contents to sit within their containers */
 justify-content: space-between; /* how to space your boxes */
}

.column {
 width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .column {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="page-title">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
 <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  <h2>Column 1</h2>
  <p>Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other. Some text that is longer than the other.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
  <h2>Column 2</h2>
  <p>Some text..</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I put a media query on the width so you have that to set you off making it fully responsive.

You can then go on to add padding to your boxes. I sometimes use another display:flex set of classes to style the inner boxes content too.